# How to automate burning ISO using NeroCmd

Tags: cmd, iso

I want a quick way to burn a ZIP file into an ISO file so I use NeroCmd.exe which is the command-line tool for Nero. When I'm using the following command:

```
NeroCmd --write --drivename "Image Recorder" --real --iso isoName rarFile.rar
```

The problem is that it prompts for the image name and I don't know if it's possible to specify it in the parameters and which parameter should I include, supposing the image name is "Image.iso".

**EDIT:**

I tried using `--output_image test.iso`, so my final code is:

```
NeroCmd --write --no_error_log --drivename "Image Recorder" --real --iso Drive --enable_abort --underrun_prot --output_image Image.iso --verify rarFile.rar
```

But no file was created, here's the console output:

```
PHASE: Unspecified
[i] Generation of disc structures started

    Creating directories
[i] Creating directories
    PHASE: Unspecified
[i] Generation of disc structures completed
    Checking discs
[i] Checking discs
Enter file name to save image to (RETURN to abort): GameSetup.iso
There is not enough space available to burn the image.
Enter file name to save image to (RETURN to abort): Not enough space available in the given location.
[!] Canceled by user

ERROR: The operation cannot be performed without user interaction!
User aborted!
```

The command works perfectly without that parameter, but the problem is it prompts.

Comment: [NeroCmd User manual](http://ftp6.nero.com/user_guides/utilities/nerocmd/NeroCMDUser.pdf) has all the command line options.

Comment: I know, but they're not detailed. For example it sais "--something specifies the image name" and i don't know wether it's the input image or output so I get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual, see link provided by David, section 5.9 Write Image:

`--output_image <filename>`

Specify output image file name if image recorder
is used to avoid prompting for file name.

Comment: Please read my edit to the topic.

Comment: I'm not using NeroCMD anymore and it's quite hard to remember...

Comment: Try to enclose filenames in double quotes and provide full path to your file destination: `nerocmd --write --real --no_error_log --drivename "Image Recorder" --iso "NameXYZ" --enable_abort --underrun_prot --output_image "D:\Image.iso" --verify rarFile.rar`. My first version of NeroCMD (early 2000s) didn't support  `--output_image`. They added it someday. Martin

Comment: Or in short `nerocmd --write --real --drivename "Image Recorder" --iso "NameXYZ" --output_image "D:\Image.iso" rarFile.rar`

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Using NeroCmd.exe to burn data files](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/RGBvgQJBgVQ)

> I have a working example of nerocmd.exe, it's in a batch file designed
>   to zip a file then burn it onto cd-rw.

```
@echo off

cd c:\

"c:\program files\winzip\wzzip" -u "c:\Well 319\Zip\Order From and
Lookup.zip" "c:\Well 319\lookup.mdb" "c:\Well 319\Order From.mdb"

"C:\Program Files\Ahead\Nero\NeroCmd.exe" --write --drivename e --real
--speed 10 --iso MCandOS_Backup --detect_non_empty_cdrw --enable_abort
--underrun_prot --create_iso_fs "C:\Well 319\Zip\Order From and
Lookup.zip" --force_erase_cdrw

@cls
```

Comment: It prompts for the file name to save image to. So your code is not helpful